# Probability: Distributing $19$ Computers to $5$ Floors with Restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

This is my last question about probability for today :-)

1)
We have $16$ desktop computers and $3$ laptops.  We also have $5$ desks in 1st floor, $4$ desks in 2nd and 3rd floor, and $3$ desks in 4th and 5th floor.

Q1) How many possibilities are there to spread out all computers and laptops to all floors?

My solution to Q1)
19!
Reason:
Something similar to this was in our script this week. We have an example: $n$ persons to $n$ places $= n!$

Q2)
In *how many* of in Q1) calculated possibilities (results) are all $3$ laptops on the same floor?

My solution to Q2)
I have a formula in my script that might be correct for this.
It is for combinations without repetitions.
According to this the solution would be $$ \frac{3!}{\frac{19!}{16!}} $$

Is this the correct way?

Many Thanks :+1:

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the probability that all three laptops are placed on the same floor or how many distributions result in all three laptops being placed on the same floor?  Please edit accordingly.

Comment: 2nd one. How many of the result from Q1) are all 3 Laptops in one floor. I am editing now.

Comment: I should have asked this earlier.  Are the desktop computers distinguishable?  Are the laptop computers distinguishable?  Your answer of $19!$ makes sense if each computer is distinguishable and each desk receives exactly one computer.

Comment: Hi Taussig. Thats a good question i have not an answer for. I think this should be so. 1 computer -> 1 desk.

Comment: If the computers are distinguishable, then the solution provided by @trueblueanil is correct.

Comment: Hi @Taussing, they dont have a unique identity. I just added a comment to trueblueanil's post

Answer (score 2):

Your ans to Q1 is correct under the assumption that each machine has a unique identity.

For Q2, in the comments you want to count **#** of ways, but have attempted to compute probability.

The laptops can be on any of the $5$ floors. Suppose they are on $1st$ floor,
then the laptops can be placed in $_5P_3 = 60$ ways, and the rest arranged in $16!$ ways.

Proceeding like this for each floor, we get $16![_5P_3 + 2(_4P_3 + \;_3P_3)]$

Comment: Hi @trueblueanil, i just asked an i think my first attempt was wrong. The machines doesnt have a unique identity. How would this change the probability?

Comment: For **Q2**, the count of favorable placements would become $_{16}C_{16}[_5C_3 + 2(_4C_3 +_3C_3)]$ against unrestricted ways of $_{19}C_3$

Comment: thank, but i have still 2 questions. How would this be effecting q1 and how did you calculated 5P3=60 ways?

Comment: $_5P_3$ represents permutations, which is equivalent to $_5C_3 \times 3!$ As for q1, once you place the $3$ laptops, the $16$ computers can be placed in only one way, thus total placements = $_{19}C_3$, or if you want to write it in full, $_{19}C_3 \times _{16}C_6$